# AngularJs - How to print modal pop div content in chrome app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am creating a Chrome app. I have to print the div content which is in modal popup using angular.js. On an HTML page it is working fine but in Chrome app `document.open()` and `document.write()` is not working. waiting for the best result? Please find the code below.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://cdn.healthscion.com/Zureka/compressfile/css/bootstrap.min.css.jgz" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.healthscion.com/Zureka/compressfile/scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js.jgz" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.healthscion.com/Zureka/compressfile/scripts/bootstrap.min.js.jgz" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.healthscion.com/Scripts/angular1.2.25.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-ng-app="UnitApp" data-ng-controller="UnitController">


        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg onPrint" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            Launch demo modal
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div ng-repeat="model in friends track by model.id">
                            My Friends Name Is: {{model.name}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="onClear()">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary onPrint" data-ng-click="onprint()">Print Code</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
    <script>
    var UnitApp = angular.module("UnitApp", []);
    UnitApp.service("UnitAppservice", function ($http) {
    });
    UnitApp.controller("UnitController", function ($scope, $compile, UnitAppservice) {
        var _ = $scope;

        _.friends = [
           { name: 'John', id: 1 },
           { name: 'Jessie', id: 2 },
           { name: 'Johanna', id: 3 },
           { name: 'Joy', id: 4 }
        ];
        _.onprint = function () {
            debugger
            $('.onPrint').css('display', 'none');
            var contents = document.getElementById("myModal").innerHTML;
            var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
            frame1.name = "frame1";
            frame1.style.position = "absolute";
            frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
            document.body.appendChild(frame1);
            var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
            frameDoc.document.open();
            frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
            frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
            frameDoc.document.write(contents);
            frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
            frameDoc.document.close();
            window.print();
        }
        _.onClear = function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            $('.onPrint').css('display', 'inline-block');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated your solution without using **UI bootstrap**

Use @media print for changing design while printing.

Check Below demo:-

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var UnitApp = angular.module("UnitApp", []);

    UnitApp.controller("UnitController", function ($scope) {
        

        $scope.friends = [
            { name: 'John', id: 1 },
            { name: 'Jessie', id: 2 },
            { name: 'Johanna', id: 3 },
            { name: 'Joy', id: 4 }
        ];

        $scope.onprint = function () { 
            window.print();
        }       
    });

})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Included here because the External Resources panel is annoying to use -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

    <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.3/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>      
    <style>
        @media print {
            body * {
                visibility: hidden;
            }

            .print-content * {
                visibility: visible;
                overflow: visible;
            }

            #mainPage * {
                display: none;
            }

            .modal {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                min-height: 550px;
                visibility: visible;
                /**Remove scrollbar for printing.**/
                overflow: visible !important;
            }

            .modal-dialog {
                visibility: visible !important;
                /**Remove scrollbar for printing.**/
                overflow: visible !important;
            }

            li {
                page-break-after: auto;
            }
            .onPrint {
                display:none;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="UnitApp">
    <div ng-controller="UnitController">

        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg onPrint" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            Launch demo modal
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog print-content" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close onPrint" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div ng-repeat="model in friends track by model.id">
                            My Friends Name Is: {{model.name}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default onPrint" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary onPrint" data-ng-click="onprint()">Print Code</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This above answer is update of your solution if you don't want to use UI bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

Please find below working Demo

Had used [UI bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) Modal popup which uses angularised Controls.

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

    $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

    $scope.friends = [
             { name: 'John', id: 1 },
             { name: 'Jessie', id: 2 },
             { name: 'Johanna', id: 3 },
             { name: 'Joy', id: 4 }
    ];

    $scope.print = function () {
        window.print();
    }


    $scope.open = function (size) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {

                    return $scope.friends;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function () {

        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };


});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

    $scope.friends = items;


    $scope.print = function () {
        window.print();
    }

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

```css
/**Modal Styles for Print**/

                @media print {
                    body * {
                        visibility: hidden;
                    }

                    #print-content * {
                        visibility: visible;
                        overflow: visible;
                    }

                    #mainPage * {
                        display: none;
                    }

                    .modal {
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 0;
                        top: 0;
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                        min-height: 550px;
                        visibility: visible;
                        /**Remove scrollbar for printing.**/
                        overflow: visible !important;
                    }

                    .modal-dialog {
                        visibility: visible !important;
                        /**Remove scrollbar for printing.**/
                        overflow: visible !important;
                    }

                    li {
                        page-break-after: auto;
                    }
                }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.2.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
            <div id="print-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="$dismiss()" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div ng-repeat="model in friends track by model.id">
                            My Friends Name Is: {{model.name}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$dismiss()" data-ng-click="onClear()">Close</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="print()">Print</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>           
        </script>
        <div id="mainPage">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="open('lg')">Launch demo modal</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```